# it's weird that the switch condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I find that these two below are equivalent, but is quit weird that, single `=` is not a relation operator but an assignment operator, why it works in the second one?

First:

```
switch (true) 
  {
    case color == 'green':case color == 'red':case color == 'blue':case color == 'pink':
      alert('colorful')
      break;
    case color == 'black':case color == 'white':
      alert('classical')
      break;
    default:
      alert('dull')
      break;              
  }
```

Second:

```
switch (color) 
  {
    case color = 'green':case color = 'red':case color = 'blue':case color = 'pink':
      alert('colorful')
      break;
    case color = 'black':case color = 'white':
      alert('classical')
      break;
    default:
      alert('dull')
      break;              
  }
```

Comment: Javascript should have stuck to constants only in `case` expressions...

Comment: Enter in "Yellow" and look at what color is after the switch http://jsfiddle.net/x5rG8/.

Comment: @user-12506 so what language is better for async and event driven tasks on the web?

Comment: @user-12506, My answer helped you ?

Comment: Why was my comment removed?

Comment: @bbuecherl I never said there was a better language for event-driven and async tasks on the web. I'n merely pointing out that JS does have its flaws. Flaws that could have easily been avoided if they gave it some more thought.

Comment: @user-12506 Yes, thats right, but i think, thats the fun about javascript ;) You always have to keep in mind that ["JavaScript (...) was created in 10 days"](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/A_Short_History_of_JavaScript) and fixing these flaws would create huge Compatibility issues.

Answer (score 8):

At the first switch statement your checking for `boolean` value. So the valid results will be either `true` or `false`.

For the second switch statement we're searching for a color. The result of assignment is the assignment value it self.

`color = 'green'` will return `green` and will be exactly like writing `case 'green':` except that it will also change the value of `color`.
**BUT** and it's a big but, you are changing the value of `color` while checking what the `color` and that may cause big side effects.

You better use the correct formal style for `case 'green':` and not other variations. Especially not `assignment` variations.

Comment: The value of color doesn't seem to always change though: `var color='red'; switch(color) { case color='green':case color='red':case color='pink': break; }; console.log(color);//'red'` Switch the initialization to `'blue'` and you get `'pink'` as expected. Very interesting.

Comment: when `red` it will not look up other cases after `case color='red'`, so it will stay defined as `red`, when looking for `blue`, it will search all cases (and execute the `color=''` stuff), so it will be changed to the last one, which is `pink` in your example

Comment: @Tibos, Indeed interesting, different languages execute it in different ways of course.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how `switch`'s work (inside the CPU), but I assume the value of `color` is temporarily stored when the switch statement is entered. Then, the result of the assignments, which equal the value that is assigned, are compared with that stored switch-value, not the variable itself. It's because, I think, you could also do this:

```
var color = 'whit'
switch(color + 'e')
// value "white" stored for comparison...
{
  case color = 'green':
  case color = 'red':
  case color = 'blue':
  case color = 'pink':
    alert('colorful')
    break;
  case color = 'black':
  // (color = 'white') == 'white'
  // 'white' is compared to the stored value
  case color = 'white':
    alert('classical')
    break;
  default:
    alert('dull')
    break;              
}
```

***UPDATE:***
In the following example, `value` is only retrieved once (at the beginning of the switch statement) but set several times (in each case statement). Ergo: only the *value* of the variable (not the variable itself) is used for comparison.

```
function Field(val){
    this.__defineGetter__("value", function(){
        var val = parseInt(Math.random() * 10);
        console.log('get: ' + val);
        return val;
    });
    this.__defineSetter__("value", function(val){
        console.log('set: ' + val);
    });
}

var field = new Field();
switch (field.value) {
    case field.value = 0:
        break
    case field.value = 1:
        break
    case field.value = 2:
        break
    case field.value = 3:
        break
    case field.value = 4:
        break
    case field.value = 5:
        break
    case field.value = 6:
        break
    case field.value = 7:
        break
    case field.value = 8:
        break
    case field.value = 9:
        break
    default:
        break
}

// output (e.g.)
// get: 5
// set: 1
// set: 2
// set: 3
// set: 4
// set: 5
```